# Animated vector drawable like Temple run chest

Tags: android, animatedvectordrawable

I'm trying to implement the Temple run like treasure chest open and close effect for gained coins or loyalty.

What I have in mind is to use an animated vector but I can't seem to get a good grip on how to do it.
Also I'm getting an error when trying it on `SDK` less than 21.

Here is the vector I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512">
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M234.536 85.605l-212.174 122.498 0 155.663 27.088 15.741 212.174 -122.499 0 -155.662 -27.088 -15.741zm-17.793 145.271l-149.061 86.06 0 -82.7 148.826 -85.925 0.235 82.565z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M243.508 246.617l-26.765 -15.741 -0.322 -113.894 27.087 15.741z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M67.682 348.13L40.918 332.389 216.743 230.876 243.508 246.617Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M49.449 223.845l0 155.663 -27.087 -15.743 0 -155.662z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M261.623 101.346L49.449 223.845 22.362 208.103 234.536 85.605Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M49.449 223.845l212.174 -122.499 0 155.662 -212.174 122.5 0 -155.663zm194.059 22.772l0 -113.894 -175.826 101.512 0 113.895 175.826 -101.513" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M261.594 90.904c-0.095 -33.501 -12.004 -57.06 -31.166 -68.089 0.062 0.036 0.125 0.068 0.187 0.103L203.527 7.177C184.226 -4.04 157.511 -2.486 128.074 14.51 69.574 48.284 22.141 130.441 22.331 197.661l0.029 10.443 27.088 15.741 212.174 -122.499 -0.028 -10.442zm-45.759 -15.421l0 0 -140.484 81.108c13.757 -42.914 44.347 -84.948 79.869 -105.456 17.463 -10.082 33.759 -13.58 47.484 -11.358 7.037 8.735 11.672 20.766 13.131 35.706z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M190.656 29.321l27.088 15.741c13.779 8.008 23 23.867 25.18 46.162L215.836 75.483c-2.179 -22.294 -11.4 -38.154 -25.18 -46.162z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M68.03 192.199L40.943 176.456 215.835 75.483 242.923 91.224Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M49.419 213.402l0.03 10.443 -27.087 -15.742 -0.031 -10.442z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M203.527 7.177l27.088 15.741C211.314 11.701 184.599 13.255 155.162 30.251L128.074 14.51c29.437 -16.996 56.152 -18.55 75.453 -7.333z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M49.419 213.402L22.331 197.661C22.141 130.441 69.574 48.283 128.073 14.51l27.088 15.741C96.662 64.026 49.229 146.183 49.419 213.402Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M155.161 30.251C213.66 -3.524 261.403 23.684 261.594 90.903l0.029 10.443L49.449 223.845 49.42 213.402C49.229 146.183 96.662 64.026 155.161 30.251ZM68.03 192.199L242.923 91.224C238.215 43.05 200.624 24.921 155.22 51.135 109.808 77.354 72.45 138.754 68.03 192.199" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#f18700"
    android:pathData="M59.51 364.73l225.347 131.18 193.999 -112.007 0 -134.778L253.127 117.946 59.128 229.951Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ff9911"
    android:pathData="M284.857 495.91L59.51 364.73 59.128 229.951 284.857 361.131Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ff9911"
    android:pathData="M284.857 361.131L59.128 229.951 253.127 117.946 478.856 249.125Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#f18700"
    android:pathData="M284.857 361.131l193.999 -112.006 0 134.778 -193.999 112.007z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M35.891 345.946l0 25.605 241.574 140.449 0 -25.605 9.747 -5.768 -227.824 -133.298 -10.595 6.118z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M59.388 347.329l-10.595 6.118 228.672 132.948 9.747 -5.768z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M462.581 218.097l-212.174 122.499 0 155.663 27.088 15.741 212.174 -122.499 0 -155.663 -27.088 -15.741zm-17.792 145.271l-149.06 86.06 0 -82.7 148.826 -85.925 0.234 82.565z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#acabb1"
    android:pathData="M471.554 265.216l0 113.895 -26.765 -15.743 -0.323 -113.894z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M295.729 480.623l-26.764 -15.742 175.824 -101.513 26.765 15.743z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M277.495 512l-27.088 -15.741 0 -155.663 27.088 15.741z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M489.669 233.838L277.495 356.337 250.407 340.596 462.581 218.097Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M277.495 356.337l212.174 -122.499 0 155.662 -212.174 122.5 0 -155.663zm194.059 22.774l0 -113.895 -175.825 101.513 0 113.894 175.825 -101.512" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#f18700"
    android:pathData="M450.462 167.464c0.056 0.032 0.114 0.062 0.17 0.094L224.903 36.378C207.266 26.129 182.841 27.575 155.881 43.139 102.306 74.071 59.022 149.04 59.197 210.602l225.729 131.18 193.999 -112.005c-0.086 -30.681 -10.952 -52.236 -28.463 -62.313z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffa834"
    android:pathData="M224.903 36.378l225.729 131.18c-17.637 -10.249 -42.062 -8.803 -69.022 6.761L155.881 43.14c26.96 -15.565 51.385 -17.011 69.022 -6.762z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ff9911"
    android:pathData="M284.927 341.783L59.197 210.603C59.023 149.041 102.306 74.071 155.881 43.14L381.61 174.32c-53.575 30.931 -96.858 105.901 -96.683 167.463z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#f18700"
    android:pathData="M381.61 174.32c53.575 -30.932 97.142 -6.105 97.316 55.457L284.927 341.783C284.752 280.221 328.035 205.251 381.61 174.32Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M49.951 200.666l-14.06 -8.174 0 51.21 241.574 140.449 0 -51.208 1.174 0.662 9.224 -5.466L60.039 194.841Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M60.039 194.841l-10.071 5.816 228.671 132.948 9.224 -5.466z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M489.64 223.397c-0.095 -33.501 -12.004 -57.061 -31.166 -68.089 0.062 0.036 0.125 0.068 0.186 0.103L431.572 139.67c-19.301 -11.217 -46.016 -9.663 -75.453 7.333 -58.499 33.774 -105.932 115.931 -105.741 183.15l0.029 10.443 27.088 15.741 212.174 -122.499 -0.029 -10.441zm-45.759 -15.422l-140.483 81.108c13.757 -42.914 44.347 -84.948 79.869 -105.456 17.463 -10.082 33.759 -13.58 47.484 -11.358 7.035 8.735 11.67 20.768 13.13 35.706z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#acabb1"
    android:pathData="M418.702 161.814l27.088 15.741c13.779 8.008 23 23.867 25.18 46.162l-27.088 -15.741c-2.179 -22.295 -11.401 -38.155 -25.18 -46.162z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M470.969 223.717L296.076 324.691 268.989 308.95 443.881 207.975Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M277.495 356.337l-27.088 -15.741 -0.029 -10.442 27.088 15.742z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#e0e0e2"
    android:pathData="M431.572 139.669l27.088 15.741c-19.301 -11.217 -46.016 -9.663 -75.453 7.333l-27.088 -15.741c29.438 -16.996 56.152 -18.55 75.453 -7.333z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M277.466 345.896l-27.088 -15.741c-0.19 -67.219 47.242 -149.378 105.741 -183.151l27.088 15.741c-58.499 33.773 -105.932 115.93 -105.741 183.151z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M383.207 162.743c58.499 -33.775 106.242 -6.567 106.433 60.652l0.029 10.443 -212.174 122.499 -0.029 -10.443C277.275 278.675 324.708 196.518 383.207 162.743ZM296.076 324.691L470.969 223.717c-4.708 -48.174 -42.299 -66.303 -87.703 -40.089 -45.412 26.219 -82.769 87.618 -87.19 141.063" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M277.465 332.942l0 51.209 -241.574 -140.449 0 -51.21z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#d8d8da"
    android:pathData="M277.465 486.395l0 25.605 -241.574 -140.449 0 -25.605z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#898890"
    android:pathData="M169.258 320.33l0 -49.44 -43.026 -24.84 -12.466 7.244 0 49.44 42.885 24.84z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#898890"
    android:pathData="M156.791 278.135l12.467 -7.245 0 49.44 -12.607 7.244z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#c6c5cb"
    android:pathData="M156.791 278.135l-43.025 -24.841 12.466 -7.244 43.026 24.84z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#acabb1"
    android:pathData="M113.766 253.294l43.025 24.841 -0.14 49.439 -42.885 -24.84z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#77767e"
    android:pathData="M134.399 277.238c-4.05 -2.338 -7.349 -0.465 
-7.362 4.188 -0.009 3.304 1.637 7.119 4.042 9.889l-0.029 10.433 6.551 
3.782 0.029 -10.433c2.405 0.006 4.068 -1.898 4.077 -5.201 0.014 
-4.654 -3.258 -10.321 -7.308 -12.658z" />
</vector>
```

And this is the link to what I want, but only the opening and closing of the chest.[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GOe_uebE74)

Might there also be a better way to do it?

Comment: `Temple run like treasure chest` is not a question . Add the code you have tried and explain our problem technically .

Comment: @The-Kamble  can you post a gif/video of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @war_Hero edited the question with the video,sorry I took long.